# Duplicate DIV onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to repeat the contents of a `DIV` when clicking on its content.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<div id="repeatTHIS"> 
   <a>text</a><br>
   <button id="button" onclick="repeat()">text</button><br>
   <a>text</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript.js

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = repeat;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('repeatTHIS');

function repeat() {
var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "repeatTHIS1" + ++i; 
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

I would also like to randomly position the replicated div, however I cannot even get my DIV to repeat.

Edit:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8b7hA/)

This actually works using jsfiddle, but not when using notepad

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate. Also keep in mind that `id` attributes are *not* meant to be duplicative; they are meant to be *unique* to the element. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: first understand and accept that id's are supposed to be unique, and having duplicate id's on the same page in the same context, errors and issues are to be expected.

Comment: the problem is that when you search element by id, the browser goes from the top of the page down, searching for the id. when it finds the ***first*** element that answers that id, it **STOPS** so you only attach your handler to the first button. and your html is mispelled, says 'onlick' instead of 'onclick', some guy answered below but deleted it, i dont know why.

Comment: @Banana - [Are you?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH5ay10RTGY&feature=kp)

Comment: _"repeat the contents of a DIV"_ This is hardly a specific description of what you expect to occur.

Comment: @Jared Farrish lol...

Comment: @Banana - Banana power, man. LOL Couldn't resist.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i actually havent heard it ever before xD

Comment: @Banana - It was seared into my brain by Tosh.0 a few years back.

Comment: It works in your jsfiddle.net demo because you're running the script in the `window.onload` handler. Look on the top, left, you'll see a select with `onLoad` selected. You could also right-click and view source of the bottom, right frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including, and running, the JS before that element ever exists.  `original` will be undefined. Move the script include below the HTML:

```
<body> 
  <div id="repeatTHIS"> 
    <button class="button" onclick="repeat()">text</button><br>
    <button class="button" onclick="repeat()">text</button><br>
    <button class="button" onclick="repeat()">text</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

And eliminate the `getElementById('button')` call, since (a) it won't work since IDs must be unique, and (b) it's unnecessary given your click handlers on the elements.

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/bxgIe

Comment: `onlick`?  or `onclick`

Comment: Additionally you could modify the javascript to run on window.onload().  Though I think the safer method would be to place the reference at the bottom as stated above.

Comment: @wifibrain Yes, I'd definitely do that if I were writing this myself, but I figure we should explain one thing at a time :-)

Comment: Firstly, thank you all for the responses. Moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>` to beneath the div worked.  Alternatively, I attempted to change `function repeat()` to `window.onload=function repeat()` but to no avail. Also tried `<body onload="repeat()">` but again it did not work.