# clone node just after of itself (not in any place...)

Tags: javascript, clone

from [Duplicate DIV onclick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588701) I get this code https://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/bxgIe

then I modify for me requeriment (clone ANY node into document):

```
<div id="repeatTHIS">
<button class="button" onclick="clonarid('repeatTHIS');">text</button>
</div>
<hr />
<a href="#" onclick="clonarid('clonarh');">Clone "hello!"</a>
<div id="clonarh">Hello!</div>
<hr />
more tags/info here...

<script>
var i = 0;
function clonarid(elid){
    var original = document.getElementById(elid);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = elid + ++ i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
</script>
```

but this ever put "new node" in END of DOC, and not just AFTER of each "id", what line I need add?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`original.parentNode.appendChild` will put the child at the *end* of the `parentNode`, which may not be right after the `original`. Use `insertAdjacentElement` instead.

```
original.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clone);
```

Comment: oh god!, is 100% true -> when I use the line `original.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', clone);` ALL run perfect, :-) thanks master!